# In VSCode how to get intellisense working for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

When developing in **Powershell** **with .NET objects**, I can't get the documentation from MSDN shown when hovering over a function, for example in this case I'd like to see all the params the func ***AuthenticateAsClient*** accepts, with info for each one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkHJS.png)

**expected result:**

something like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DE6U.png) or [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moSpS.png)

how can i get it working auto instead of manually browsing to the [msdn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasserver?view=net-8.0) every time?

I tried the official powershell extension in vscode per microsoft guielines.

this is what i get, a numb popup: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyer9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of v2024.0.0 of the **[PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for Visual Studio Code**:

**IntelliSense support for calling *.NET methods*** is limited to:

- *read-only display* of *all overloads* that is only shown while the method *name* is being type; once you *tab-complete* or start typing *arguments*, the display goes away.

  - To show the overloads again on demand, place the cursor *before* the opening `(` and press <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>
- showing the method *signatures only*, i.e. the parameter names and types- no *description* of the method or its parameters is shown.

In other words, there is **currently *no* support for**:

- (a) *showing* an overload signature (parameter names) *as arguments are being typed*.
- (b) allowing *selecting* one of the overloads so as to auto-complete a call to that overload with argument placeholders named for the parameters.
- (c) showing concise method descriptions from the online documentation of built-in .NET types

[GitHub issue #1356](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1356) discusses potentially improving method-call IntelliSense in the future, but there are *implementation challenges*:

- (a) is problematic, given PowerShell's lack of *static* typing, though it's conceivable to let the user manually cycle through available overloads in the same way that the C# extension does, albeit without type awareness.
- (b) *may* be feasible, if the IntelliSense feature allows calling a Visual Studio Code *snippet* in response to a user selection.

---

It is important to note that direct use of .NET APIs is an *advanced* use case in PowerShell; fortunately, support for *PowerShell-native* commands an operator is better:

**IntelliSense support for calling *PowerShell-native* commands**:

- Display of the [syntax diagram(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) of a command being typed (parameter names, along with its synopsis (the concise description shown in the `SYNOPSIS` section of `Get-Help`'s output):

  - You may have to click on the `>` at the right edge of the relevant line of the IntelliSense pop-up in order to show an additional panel with the syntax diagrams and the description.
  - As of v2024.0.0, there are the following **limitations** for commands implemented as  *script files* (`*.ps1`), reported in [GitHub issue #4904](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/4904):

    - Their synopsis is *not* shown, because their [comment-based help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comment_Based_Help) is seemingly not consulted.
    - The formatting of their syntax diagrams is broken: they individual diagrams aren't separated with empty lines and instead form one long string without line breaks, resulting in arbitrary line wrapping.
- Completion of individual parameters, along with displaying their data type.

  - **Limitation**: Parameter *descriptions* aren't shown.
- Once a command name has been completed or typed in full, you can invoke its *online help* in the default web browser, assuming the given command has a help URL associated with it, by default via <kbd>Ctrl+F1</kbd>

Comment: thanks! so basically you're saying that everyone who are programming in PowerShell, don't have intellisense autocomplete and must browse manually to MSDN to get their docs for each .NET func they're using?

Comment: @ShakedIlan: Indeed, there's currently no integration with online documentation. However, it is important to note that direct use of .NET APIs is an *advanced* use case in PowerShell; fortunately support for _PowerShell-native_ commands an operators is better, including the ability to invoke the online help for a given command in the default web browser - please see my update.